# Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object while setting special price to null

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I am trying to change the products prices but when I set special prices to null then it gives me an error "Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object".
Is there any mistake in my code?

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->load($prodId); 
        $prod->setPrice($newPrice)->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'price');
        $prod->setSpecialPrice('')->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'special_price');
        $prod->setSpecialFromDate('')->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'special_from_date');
        $prod->setSpecialToDate('')->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'special_to_date');
```

Comment: Hi, wich magento version ur useing? Check Mage_Catalog_Model_Product for method addAttributeUpdate(). Try this method to update single product attribute values. F.e. $prod->addAttributeUpdate('special_price', '', $storeId);

Comment: Hi Stefan, I am using magento 1.9. I tried your code but it did not remove special prices.

Comment: Are you run this code from admin or frontend?

Comment: Hi, try $prod->addAttributeUpdate('special_price', NULL, $storeId);. Which store id did you set?

Comment: Hi R.S. I am running this code on admin.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I tried this same code. But I am unable to remove special prices.